# JAXB - Cannot figure out how to use refID properly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**Goal**: Marshalling and unmarshalling the clinic.xml correctly

**Problem**: Reading out the id's of the physiotherapist (people who work in the clinic)

This is the **clinic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<clinic clinicNumber="1">
    <name>ClinicStackOverFlow</name>
    <address>Deadbrains</address>
    <zipCode>SomeZip</zipCode>
    <city>City</city>
    <phoneNumber>069441341341</phoneNumber>
    <!-- LIST OF THE ID's of physiotherapists that work here -->
    <physiotherapists>1</physiotherapists>
    <physiotherapists>2</physiotherapists>
</clinic>
```

**Clinic.java**

```
package fysio.shared.domain;
import com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Clinic {
    /**
     * The identifier of a clinic
     */
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IDStringAdapter.class)
    private String clinicNumber;

    /**
     * The name of a clinic
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * The address where the clinic is located
     */
    private String address;

    /**
     * The zip code of a clinic
     */
    private String zipCode;

    /**
     * The city a clinic is located in
     */
    private String city;

    /**
     * The phone number of a clinic
     */
    private String phoneNumber;

    @XmlIDREF
    private List<Physiotherapist> physiotherapists;

    /**
     * The default constructor for Jaxb
     */
    public Clinic() {
    }


    public Clinic(String clinicNumber, String name, String address, String zipCode, String city, String phoneNumber, List<Physiotherapist> physiotherapists) {
        this.clinicNumber = clinicNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.physiotherapists = physiotherapists;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of a clinic
     *
     * @return The number of a clinic
     */
    public String getClinicNumber() {
        return clinicNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of a clinic
     *
     * @param clinicNumber the number of a clinic
     */
    public void setClinicNumber(String clinicNumber) {
        this.clinicNumber = clinicNumber;
    }


    public List<Physiotherapist> getPhysiotherapists() {
        return physiotherapists;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the physiotherapists of a clinic
     *
     * @param physiotherapists The Physiotherapists of a clinic
     */
    public void setPhysiotherapists(List<Physiotherapist> physiotherapists) {
        this.physiotherapists = physiotherapists;
    }

    /**
     * adds a physiotherapist to a clinic
     *
     * @param physiotherapist The physiotherapist that needs to be added to a clinic
     */
    public void addPhysiotherapist(Physiotherapist physiotherapist) {
        physiotherapists.add(physiotherapist);
    }


}
```

We have a list of physiotherapists (in xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<physiotherapists>
    <physiotherapist physiotherapistNumber="1">
        <clinic>1</clinic>
        <name>Henk</name>
    </physiotherapist>
    <physiotherapist physiotherapistNumber="2">
        <clinic>8</clinic>
        <name>Klaas</name>
    </physiotherapist>
</physiotherapists>
```

Physiotherapist.java (singular)

```
package fysio.shared.domain;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Physiotherapist {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String physiotherapistNumber;

    @XmlIDREF
    private Clinic clinic;

    private String name;

    public Physiotherapist() {
        //Default empty constructor for JAXB
    }

    public Physiotherapist(String name, Clinic clinic) {
        this.clinic = clinic;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Clinic getClinic() {
        return clinic;
    }

    public String getPhysiotherapistNumber() {
        return physiotherapistNumber;
    }

    public void setPhysiotherapistNumber(String physiotherapistNumber) {
        this.physiotherapistNumber = physiotherapistNumber;
   {}
}
```

Physiotherapists.java (plural)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "physiotherapists")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Physiotherapists {

    @XmlElement(name = "physiotherapist")
    private List<Physiotherapist> physiotherapistList;

    public Physiotherapists() {
        //empty constructor for xml parsing
        physiotherapistList = new ArrayList<Physiotherapist>();
    }

    public List<Physiotherapist> getPhysiotherapistList() {
        return physiotherapistList;
    }
}
```

And finally the unmarshalling part:

```
try {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Clinic.class, Physiotherapist.class, Physiotherapists.class);

    File clinicXML = new File("src/test/resources/data/xml/clinic.data");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Clinic clinicXMLData = (Clinic) unmarshaller.unmarshal(clinicXML);


    File fysiotherapistXML = new File("src/test/resources/data/xml/physiotherapist.data");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller2 = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Physiotherapists ph = (Physiotherapists) unmarshaller2.unmarshal(fysiotherapistXML);

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both unmarshallers do the best they can. I get a nice list of physiotherapist from unmarshaller 2 but I don't get anything about the physiotherapists from the clinic unmarshaller:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw15n.jpg (stack didn't let me upload pics)

I kinda lost it... not knowing anymore whats wrong and correct. Tried many solutions online, understand the most of them but still missing something.

(It's a school project and it's not yet refactored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How should it be possible to get the physiotherapists (PT) references into the Clinic objects when unmarshalling the PT list has no connection whatsoever to those Clinic objects? The Clinics have been built from the XML data, and there are no PTs in it, period.

For XmlID and XmlIDREF to work, i.e., to store an object reference in the field annotated XmlIDREF there must be an object of suitable type and with the matching value in its XmlID field within the same XML file.

You must combine the XML data into a single file.

Seeing that you reference the Clinic from the PT and the PTs from the Clinic, I'm afraid that you'll encounter difficulties in one direction even then. (I might be wrong - it's too long since I tried this.)

Now I think that you may not want to merge the XML files anyway. To solve your predicament, I suggest that you drop the ID and IDREF annotations and set the links "by hand". A single pass through the PT list is sufficient, a simple and robust solution.